# Relationships between 3 Entities in a ternary relationship

Tags: database, entity, relationship, entity-relationship, erd

we are tasked with creating a database which has three entities team, user, course. **A course will have multiple students and multiple teams in it**. A student and professor can belong to many courses. However, a user with the type of student **can only belong to one team in a specific course**, but they can **belong to other teams in different courses**.  We are currently trying to figure out how to display this relationship. We are also leaning towards teams being a weak entity which depends on course. So far we have [two versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f48ul.jpg) of how we believe the entities and relationships will look like. Would someone be able to tell if we are on the correct track, the weak entity is throwing us off. We also are a bit confused on the cardinality for the ternary relationship.
**We only put primary keys in the diagram to simplify it.**

A **user** has the following attributes: name, primary key(userID), userType(either admin, student,teacher), and email.
A **course** has the following attributes: course name, primary key(course id), start date, and end date.
A **team** is a weak entity with the following attributes: course id, team number. Primary key(course id, team number).

Thank you to anyone who may be able to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the **course** table should not have both **team** and **user** linked to it, only **team** should be linked to it, to specify what **course** is the **team** for. My ERD diagram would look something similar to this : [image: ERD diagram]

**Team_member** is an associative entity used to solve the many-to-many relationship between **team** and **user**, since each user can belong to many teams, and each team can have many members, so it should have a composite key made up of user_id and team_id, to record each member within a **team**, and **team** should have a foreign key of course_id to specify its course.